# openpyxl- TypeError: expected <class 'str'> when entering chart data

Tags: python, charts, openpyxl, xlsx

Good day,

I'm trying to create an Excel chart with openpyxl but I'm having some difficulties when assigning the data to the chart. The problem snipped of the program code is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (SurfaceChart3D, Reference, Series)
from openpyxl.chart.axis import SeriesAxis
from os import startfile

book_name = "3DChart.xlsx"

dictionary = {}
dictionary["X1"] = [8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1]
dictionary["X2"] = [8, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8]
dictionary["X3"] = [8, 8, 8.1, 8, 8]
dictionary["X4"] = [8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
dictionary["X5"] = [8, 8, 8, 8, 8]

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dictionary, index=['Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3', 'Y4', 'Y5'])

try:
     with pd.ExcelWriter(book_name, mode='a', if_sheet_exists='new', engine='openpyxl') as writer:      
         dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Distribution")
         
except FileNotFoundError:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(book_name) as writer:       
        dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Distribution")

wb = Workbook("3DChart.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

surface_chart = SurfaceChart3D()
values = Reference(ws, min_col=2, max_col=6, min_row=2, max_row=6)
labels = Reference(ws, min_col=2, max_col=6, min_row=2, max_row=6)
surface_chart.add_data(values)
surface_chart.set_categories(labels)
surface_chart.title = "Distribution"

ws.surface_chart(surface_chart, "G1")

ws.add_chart(surface_chart, "G29")

startfile(book_name)
```

This code results in the following traceback and error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  line 32, in <module>
    surface_chart.add_data(values)

  line 183, in add_data
    series = SeriesFactory(ref, title_from_data=titles_from_data)

  line 24, in SeriesFactory
    source = NumDataSource(numRef=NumRef(f=values))

  line 100, in __init__
    self.f = f

  line 35, in __set__
    super(Nested, self).__set__(instance, value)

  line 67, in __set__
    value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)

  line 57, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))

TypeError: expected <class 'str'>
```

When trying with a simple data list this seems to work. I've tried playing around with the format of my dictionary but always seem to get the same error on the add_data function.

Thanks,

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full traceback.  It's difficult for anyone to know where the problem in your code is without it.

Comment: Sorry abotu that. wouldn't let me post so much code without more text. I've added a little text and included the full traceback.

Comment: @JosephJoeSoltan Is there any update on this? Where you able to resolve this error?